# What are the guidelines for omitting particles?

Tags: particles, ellipsis

I've recently discovered that certain particles could be omitted from a Japanese sentence (to help make it shorter), and still preserve the original meaning. Unfortunately, most resources about this topic that I've looked at are vague at best; and some even contradict each other!

This question is really a few sub questions (but I really don't think each one deserves its own thread since they're so closely related.) The answers don't have to be too detailed; just general points are fine. Anyways, the things I'd like to know are:

- Which particles can be omitted from sentences?
- Does the omission of particles make a sentence informal/impolite?
- When can particles be dropped? (e.g. How can you decide that it's okay both socially and grammatically)
- Can multiple particles be dropped in a single sentence?

Comment: __Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar__ by __Makino, Tsutsui__ has some guidelines about that matter.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Which particles can be omitted from sentences?

は, が, and を are often dropped; に sometimes. か, as a sentence-final question particle, can be replaced with intonation.

> Does the omission of particles make a sentence informal/impolite?

Informal yes, but not necessarily impolite. Dropping particles is only for spoken Japanese, so you won't see it in (proper) writing.

> When can particles be dropped? (e.g. How can you decide that it's okay)

When the situation allows. Speaking informally to someone above you or with whom you don't have a close relationship is impolite. But if the situation lets you speak informally, you can.

In situations where polite Japanese is called for (speaking to your boss/teacher/doctor/etc or giving a formal speech/presentation), all particles must be kept in the sentence. Omitting particles does not change the meaning of the sentence or make it incorrect per se, since the missing particles can be inferred from context and word order, but it does make the sentence informal and thus unsuitable for polite contexts.

As noted above, in writing (excluding Twitter, blogs, and other informal variants of writing) all particles must be kept.

If you are unsure as to whether to keep or omit particles, a good rule of thumb is to err on the side of keeping the particles.

> Can multiple particles be dropped in a single sentence?

Yes.

Examples:

> これあげるよ。（＝これ**を**あげるよ。） You can have this. (lit. "I'll give this [to you].")
>
> おまえ昨日、学校行った？（＝おまえ**は**昨日、学校**に**行った**か**。） Did you go to school yesterday? (*slightly masculine*)
>
> あたしスイカ好き。（＝あたし**は**スイカ**が**好き。） I like watermelon. (*feminine*)

が and を, as you recall, are dropped when the part of the sentence they mark is made into the scope/topic (marked by は):

> 図書館でこの本を借りました。 I borrowed this book at the library.
>
> この本をは図書館で借りました。 (making この本を the scope)
>
> この本は図書館で借りました。 (replaced ungrammatical をは with は)

Comment: Your answer is overall correct, but the usage of the word 'scope' is misleading. In ordinary usage of this word, the scope of 'この本は' in the sentence 'この本は図書館で借りました' is '図書館で借りました'. You can simply say 'the phrase that is marked by は' if you want to refer to 'この本'.

Comment: There is one more case: omitting "の" to make formal word compounds in written Japanese.  This contradicts your "must".

Comment: Great answer! A perhaps pedantic comment: The idea that everything has a particle in theory, which is either "dropped" or not, is actually relatively modern. In earlier forms of Japanese, there were many cases where "no particle" was most correct, particularly marking subjects and direct objects: 花咲く都, 兎追いし彼の山, etc. Thus: (1) The modern "use ALL the particles" written style is not the Ideal form from which particles are dropped, but an artificially hypercorrected form; (2) Writing quoting or emulating older forms of Japanese may, grammatically, omit particles that would otherwise be expected.

Comment: @Axioplase Can you expand on that thought? It seems to me that creating a new compound like 国際関係 is a pre-grammatical process and so a の would not be expected in the first place. Am I misunderstanding the point?

Comment: Matt: here's an example from a résumé: 交換留学で並行分散言語について*修論作成*及び研究.  I am pretty sure there is a dropped の between 修論 and 作成.

Comment: @Axioplase Hm, interesting. I see that as a straightforward compound word with no need for の, but I admit that's an intuitive judgment rather than a rigorous theoretical one.

Answer (score 4):

> The modern "use ALL the particles" written style is not the Ideal form from which particles are dropped, but an artificially hypercorrected form
>   [<sub>from a comment by Matt</sub>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/what-are-the-guidelines-of-omitting-particles#comment7168_3152)

Surely languages change over time. Using all the particles is the current correct usage. English orthography was at one time far less fixed than it is now, but that does not make modern standard orthography "artificial and hypercorrected" (or, of course, the older orthography "wrong").

Some older English writing also contains contractions that are no longer used but were once normal. However, they were still contractions.

I would tentatively suggest that the particles were always logically necessary, and that what varies over time is the acceptability of their omission in formal use.

A parallel case might be the omission of "that" in a sentence like "the cake (that) I ate". This cannot be done in French or Spanish, but is regularly done in English. However the omitted "that" is always logically there. The acceptability of its omission may vary with time, place and context.

Answer (score 1):

https://cotoacademy.com/omitting-particles-japanese-can-skip-wa-o-ga-e-japanese/

This article has a chart that breaks down usage rules for the different types of particles in a table.

> Omitting particles in casual spoken Japanese is very common.  But when can you do this – and how should you do it?
> In this short blog we will show you which particles can be skipped and which must remain.
> Japanese Particles can be omitted only in conversational sentences, not in written language.
> The first rule about Japanese particles is that omitting them can only occur in spoken Japanese. So when you are writing Japanese – remember to include them!
> Japanese sentence patterns determine some relationships between words
> As the heading above implies, the basic Japanese sentence pattern has an order which informs the relationship between certain words.
> The basic sentence pattern in Japanese has the word order ” S is O is / to V. ” (Subject is object is / to verb) , and its role can be understood by the position of the word even without particles. So, in a basic japanese sentence「は」and「を/が」 can be omitted.
> Let’s look at a more detailed chart below that explains some of the common examples of omitted particles in Japanese Grammar.

Comment: When copy-pasting sentences word for word, please use > for indicating the quotation. I think it would be more useful if you can rephrase the most important points in your own words (or alternatively just leave a comment with this link).

Comment: @Earthliŋ wouldn't the last suggestion violate the policy to always quote/summarize the main point of a link, in case the link goes dead?

Comment: @Sam Link-only *comments* are common, and they just get (flagged and) removed in case the link stops working. Indeed the better way is to summarize the relevant content of the link and post it as an answer.