# anata no koto suki vs anata ga suki

Tags: particles, particle-が

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the こと in sentences such as あなたのことが好きだ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-in-sentences-such-as-%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9f%e3%81%ae%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8c%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d%e3%81%a0)
>   [What are the guidelines of omitting particles?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/what-are-the-guidelines-of-omitting-particles)

It is possible to say both of these:

- あなたが好きです
- あなたのこと好きです

The adjective 好き is usually used with the particle が to express what we like. What is the difference between these sentences? and why is the particle can be omitted in the second case?

**EDIT**

I just saw this question [What is the こと in sentences such as あなたのことが好きだ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2102/570) and it answers my first question, but it doesn't give any hints about the second one.

Comment: It makes more sense to only vary one thing (Either presence/absence of のこと or が but not both). I think the comparison of あなたが好きです against あなた好きです would be more meaningful.

Comment: 好き is not a verb.

Comment: I don't think there's anything about the first part that isn't covered in: [What is the こと in sentences such as あなたのことが好きだ?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-in-sentences-such-as-%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9f%e3%81%ae%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8c%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d%e3%81%a0), and then the part about particles is covered in the one Flaw links to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common to drop particles in casual speak when there's no ambiguity about what is being said. But strictly speaking, it's not "correct" to drop the particle there.

Also, 好き is a な-adjective, not a verb.