# Obligatory zero particle

Tags: grammar, particles, zero-particle

Sometimes, particles are omitted.

I've read, however, that this can be analyzed as inserting a "zero particle" instead.  See for example [Particle omission or zero particle](https://jps.library.utoronto.ca/index.php/twpl/article/view/6178/3167) by Mitsuaki Shimojo.  See also [Matt's comment on a related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/what-are-the-guidelines-of-omitting-particles#comment7168_3152).

Are there situations where a zero particle is required?  That is, situations where adding any particle would change the meaning or make the sentence incorrect?

Are there situations where a zero particle is strongly preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of one instance -- a noun phrase with も "also" cannot also take は/が/を. Because the NP still has grammatical case despite having non-overt case, this can be analysed as the topic/subject/object marker being obligatorily zero.

This isn't the case for other particles like だけ or など though.

Comment: (1) Although it is true that が and を are usually omitted when used with も, the combination もが and をも also exist.  (2) は is not a case particle.  I think that がは→は is a better example of obligatory omission of a case particle.

Comment: True enough, but I think をも is a fossilised form in the modern language.

Comment: @jogloran:  I hear をも all the time.

Comment: @istrasci: From Martin "A Reference Grammar of Japanese" §2.3: "In standard spoken Japanese these two particles are obligatorily suppressed... where we would expect *N ga wa/mo* and *N o wa/mo* we find only *N wa/mo*: the opposition of the prime cases of subject vs. object are neutralised." This might be a development in the language, a register difference, or else the grammar might be plain wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when the subject of a sentence of neutral description (現象文) is pronoun これ・それ or a noun modified with この・その.

(Opening the refrigerator) あっ、この納豆 φ 腐ってる！

Without この that would be あっ、納豆が腐ってる！.

この納豆が腐ってる is "it is this natto that is rotten" and would be ungrammatical for a sentence of neutral description.
この納豆は… would be a contrasive sentence.

Comment: But I say あっ、納豆腐ってる！

Comment: Me too. That can be considered omittion of が as well because using が is obviously fine too.