neutral-description が / は when Xが is variously modified
I'm looking for clarification about a passage from this guide about が VS は on Reddit. I'm going to use some technical terms from Susumu Kuno's "The Structure of the Japanese Language, Chapter II.2, also introduced here. In the guide on Reddit, the author says:

Below are subjects that are within the universe of discourse by
default: [...]
Subjects modified with additional information, such as この / その / あの,
今日の, etc (because this additional phrasing introduces it first).

They then give the following examples:

「今日の天気は寒いねー。」 (「今日の」 introduces 「天気」 into the universe of discourse.
If が were used here, it would be exhaustive-listing (see below), which
would be a rare case.)
「あの牛は草を食べている。」 (「あの」 introduces 「牛」 into the universe of discourse. If
が were used here, it would be exhaustive-listing (see below), which
would be a rare case.)

The first example contains a poor collocation according to this answer and this website, so I'm not sure how reliable it is.
As for the second one, I've gathered mixed opinions on whether「あの牛が草を食べている。」is necessarily a case of exhaustive-listing が as opposed to neutral-description が.
As a premise, and based on answers such as this, I understand that「牛が草を食べている。」is a case of neutral-description が where the speaker has just noticed that the cow (if already in the universe of discourse) / a cow (if not yet in the universe of discourse and in the presence of multiple cows) is eating some grass. I also understand that 「牛は草を食べている。」would be unusual in daily conversation unless は is interpreted as the contrastive は.
I'm not really sure how any modifiers of 牛 would change this distribution of が and は. This is the main point of my question.
I've also noticed that the modifiers introduced in the quotes above are all deictics of place and time. I wonder if this property also plays a role.
So I'd like to ask which one is better, 牛は or 牛が, in a few sentences where 牛 is variously modified. I'm trying to focus on neutral description, so I'm adding these conditions:
-The speaker has just noticed that the cow is eating grass.
-The cow is not being contrasted (e.g. to a horse that is not eating grass).
-The cow is not under focus (e.g. we are not answering a question such as: which animal is eating grass?). So, under these conditions:
Scenario 1: a single cow is in the field (other animals may be there).
1a) あの牛 (が? は?) 草を食べている。(deictic - the speaker is pointing at the cow)
2a) あそこにいる牛 (が? は?) 草を食べている。(deictic in noun-modifying clause)
3a) 白い牛 (が? は?) 草を食べている。(non-deictic modifier)
Scenario 2: same set of sentences but this time many cows are in the field (牛が / 牛は, though, still refers to a single cow):
1b) あの牛 (が? は?) 草を食べている。(deictic - the speaker is pointing at the cow)
2b) あそこにいる牛 (が? は?) 草を食べている。(deictic in noun-modifying clause)
3b) 白い牛 (が? は?) 草を食べている。(non-deictic modifier)

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15381

Thank you. I agree that the zero particle is related.

I think if it's spoken conversation, the most common way would be to leave out が and は (as well as を) entirely (and also say 食べてる instead of 食べている. If I were to use が or は, then I'd use が if spoken I think for neutral description.
If it's written, both are fine for neutral description IMO. However, if you say は it might be interpreted that the cow habitually eats grass (perhaps including now), as opposed to be eating grass in this instance. If you say が you are talking about the current instance.
Suppose there is a cow that is NOT eating grass right now. If you say あの牛は草を食べる then it means the cow habitually eats grass. If you say あの牛が草を食べる then you are saying the cow will eat grass (in the near future like within 5 minutes).
In case of は it could also mean that that cow eats grass but not others. In case of が it could mean you are specifying which cow eats grass (in this interpretation it could refer to habitual grass eating).

Thank you for your reply. Your example [あの牛が草を食べる] referring to a time when the cow will shortly start eating reminded me of this explanation: (https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/n3o8nr/a_thorough_guide_to_%E3%81%AF_vs_%E3%81%8C/)
[夜が明ける: "(I'm seeing) this night is dawning" (neutral-description が; a description of what the singer is seeing/experiencing). 夜は明ける: "Nights (always) dawn" (spoken as a general fact)]
Do you think these are related, in that in both neutral-description が refers to imminent future events?

However, again in reference to [あの牛が草を食べる], doesn't this sentence violate the constraint described here? (https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/7073/obligatory-zero-particle, - as described in the reply by user4092.)
