# Is 寝るの朝 a set phrase?

Tags: meaning, set-phrases, manga

In a manga I am reading, I found this sentence:

> "私も最近は寝るの朝の９時くらい"

I understand its meaning from context:

> I also sleep around 9 in the morning these days.

But I don't get why there is の between 寝る and 朝. I would like to see word to word translation. Is it a contraction of

> 私も最近は寝るの**は**朝の９時くらい

or something like that?

Source: (働かない二人)
http://yamakamu.com/archives/4077130.html

Comment: I think you've got it https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/what-are-the-guidelines-of-omitting-particles. I'd wait for a native to weigh in.