# Spoken Japanese, words ending with わ used as the topic

Tags: grammar, spoken-language

So consider a noun in Japanese such as 毛皮 that ends in a わ mora. If you were to construct a sentence with such a word as the topic it would have some structure like 毛皮は which when spoken out loud, would have the わ sounds repeated twice in a row. Grammatically, I assume the topic marker は should be included in such as sentence and in formal written language would probably be included, but when speaking, would native speakers drop the topic marking particle in this case in order to sound more natural?

Comment: Since I'm not a native speaker and can't answer with any certainty, I'll comment instead.  :)  I haven't encountered the word [毛皮]{けがわ} that often in speech -- it's simply not a common topic among the folks I know.  :)  The few times that I can remember hearing it, and where it was the topic, the は was not dropped.  I recall a difference in pitch, where the //wa// topic particle is pronounced at a slightly higher or slightly lower pitch than the //-wa// at the end of //keɡawa//.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you are worrying about this, but there is nothing wrong with saying *wa* twice in succession. It's not unnatural at all. When the topic ends with わ, we simply say 毛皮は *kegawa-wa*, 川は *kawa-wa*, チワワは *chiwawa-wa*, and so on. Nothing special will happen.

The topic marker [は is commonly omitted in speech anyway](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3151/5010), but that's a different phenomenon that happens regardless of the last sound of the topic.