# Why is there no を in 二人とも自分の話ばかりして?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-を

I'm reading [this story](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-lessons/1-2-the-north-wind-and-the-sun/) and am trying to understand the structure of this sentence:

> 二人{ふたり}とも自{じ}分{ぶん}の話{はなし}ばかりして、人{ひと}の話{はなし}を聞{き}きません。

In the second part, 話 is used with the direct object particle を as I would have expected. But in the first part, where I would also have expected 話をして, there's no を. Why is that? Apparently ばかり is also a particle (says [this page](https://www.thoughtco.com/japanese-particle-bakari-2027853)) – does it displace を, like は sometimes does? But [this page](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/expressions-for-numbers-and-amounts/#3) says that ばかり can be combined with が and を.

Comment: I think this possibly answers your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3151

Comment: @EddieKal: The accepted answer there says that omitting particles makes a sentence informal. My impression (which may well be wrong) was that while the dialogue in the story is sometimes informal, the narration is formal. Would you say that the sentence I quoted is somewhat informal and would require を after 話 in formal language?

Comment: I think ばかり is a particle in its own right, as you point out in the question, so it's somewhere between a simple case of particle dropping and a swap, which might contribute to its being less informal. I am under the impression that 自分の話をばかりする is less formal than 自分の話をばかりをする, but not exactly informal. That's just my opinion. I upvoted (+1) your question when I first read it because I wasn't 100% sure either.

Comment: @EddieKal: Thanks for the explanation! Did you mean to have two を in the second expression? Or did you mean just 自分の話ばかりをする? (I was under the impression that there can't be two を in a sentence.)

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Nice catch! 自分の話ばかりをする is what I meant to say. I bungled it and accidentally put two を's when multitasking (juggling writing that comment with editing another post)